# understanding issue about RAM on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Sometimes we got Java Heap Space error, and than we are increasing the JVM RAM limit (by Xmx value).
i have 2 questions about it please:

1) how can i know how much mapers and reducers should i have in cluster after I changing the Xmx value? i meant if i have node with 32G RAM, and have Xmx value for example to 5G, does it mean i can use only 6 maps and reducers (5*6=30G) ?

2) why does it happen at all? i tried to read all this forum and didn't find the answer. if i have query on hive which reading a lot of data, i know the job settings the number of mappers which go and read the data from the MFS. each chunk of data goes to map, and up to the RAM. why i need to increase the Xmx , can't hive just split the data to more mappers? lets say i have job with 1000 mappers, and i got the HEAP space issue, can't hive give me 2000 mappers and it will fix the issue (each map will take less RAM, because it use less data) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to post the code that you're running? Typically Heap space errors are due to people accumulating huge sets of data in memory (Lists, Sets or Maps).

Comment: you are write, it is join of 2 big tables. but why each mapper getting so much data to RAM? cant hadoop split it to more mapers?

Comment: What type of join / what do you anticipate the cardinality of the joins to be (1:1, 1:M or M:M). And can you post code / hive statements?

Comment: this is the query:    
    select * from DB1.Table1 i join DB2.Table2 c on i.X=c.X limit 100;
what else details you need?

Thanks!